# How to increase cordova splash screen dimension size after upgrade to cordova 11 and android API 32

Tags: android, cordova, android-splashscreen, android-api-31

I just update cordova to 11 and android API to 32.

Then found that the `cordova-plugin-splashscreen` no longer support, have to change to API splash screen.

So, in config.xml, Need to add the following line:

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/android/splash/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
```

However, I found that the size is being reduce, it become smaller.

Is there workaround or any way to increase the dimension size?

[This page](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions) mentions that `Everything outside the circle will be invisible (masked).`.

Comment: No solution on this. We just edit the image file to fix it.

Comment: if we try it as vector image, it is working